# How to change the product image position using CSV?

Tags: magento-1.8, product, csv, importexport

I'm trying to update Product's image position using CSV file.
I've already uploaded images in Products.

**So how to change already inserted product image position using CSV file?**

Answer (score 2):

Before going to this step, you must know about all images name,

[image]

Use MAGMI to import CSV file.